# Scraping from specific website has stopped working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So a couple of weeks ago I wrote this program which sucessfuly scraped some info on some online store, but now it has stopped working without me changing the code?

Could this be something that has been changed within the website itself or is there something wrong with my code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?ProductId=7104665(eCsf_RetekProductCatalog_MegastoreContinenteOnline_Continente)'

res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

priceInfo = soup.find('div', class_='pricePerUnit').text

priceInfo = priceInfo.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace(' ', '')

productName = soup.find('div', class_='productTitle').text.replace('\n', ' ')

productInfo = (soup.find('div', class_='productSubtitle').text
               + ', ' + soup.find('div', class_='productSubsubtitle').text)

print('Nome do produto: ' + productName)
print('Detalhes: ' + productInfo)
print('Custo: ' + priceInfo)
```

I know for a fact that what im searching for does exist and the url is still valid, so what could be the issue?
I separated the priceInfo into 2 lines because the error exists in the first declaration, since it returns a NoneType which has no text attribute

Comment: 1) websites can block scrapers based on user agent very simply 2) beautifulsoup doesn't run Javascript if site is dynamically rendered

Comment: Every website has a robots.txt file you can read to find out what you can scrape. It can also mean that website changed layout and the elements that you scraped aren't at the same place they were when you wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is bit multistep.

1. Try calling the page you want to scrape in Firefox once
2. Use browser_cookie3 lib to extract cookies
3. ensure they are not expired
4. Use the cookies in requests.get(url, cookies=browser_cookie3.firefox())
5. Use the headers as below

Hope it works!! Happy scraping

Have tried on my own and it works!!

```
 headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8',
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however im still having the same error, the only line i've changed is `res = requests.get(url, cookies=browser_cookie3.firefox(),  headers=headers)` with headers being the one you provided. Should i do anything else regarding the cookies?

Comment: Have you opened the site in Firefox and extracted the cookies? Print and check the cookiejar

Comment: I've opened the site, but how do i extract the cookies? Sorry if it's obvious

Comment: you could simply follow https://github.com/borisbabic/browser_cookie3/ for extracting the cookies

Comment: Thank you for the replies, ill be trying what you suggested